# Expected downtime to reboot a multi az rds instance without failover to apply some static parameter changes

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, devops, database-administration

I would like to know how much downtime should I expect to reboot an multi az rds instance **without failover**. I want to apply some static parameter changes. The instance is t2 medium with 100 GiB storage. It's running postgres 9.6. I am not looking for exact number but an estimate.

Answer (score 1):

I recently rebooted db.t3.micro RDS postgres 10.6 instance without failover, and it took about 1min when the status became `available` again, DB size 18GB.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience that would take about 5 to 10 minutes, but I'm not sure if the DB would be down and inaccessible the whole time. Please don't make any critical business decisions based on my estimate though. If this is a critical issue, then you should create a copy of the database from a snapshot and test out the parameter changes on the copy.

If you are concerned with limiting the downtime, just add a replica, make the changes and let it failover, then once the changes are done remove the replica.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My concern was that I might need to do a reboot without failover as I learned from somewhere that static parameter changes will only be applied if reboot is done without failover.

But I tested this scenario and found that it also works if I reboot with failover.